# Java Regular Expression Group OR Operator

Tags: java, regex

I am using the `java.util.regex` and I have a hard time constructing a regular expression that will extract this type of text:

```
Manufacturer : ABC Inc. Price : ...
Manufacturer : ABC Inc. Quantity : ...
```

What I want is the company name out of different text that followed the text `Manufacturer :` but it might follow `Price` or `Quantity` which I don't really know how to implement it in Java.

What I have done so far:

```
Pattern.compile("Manufacturer #:(.*)Price")
Pattern.compile("Manufacturer #:(.*)Quantity")
```

And I can extract the part in parenthese using

```
Pattern mypattern = Pattern.compile("Manufacturer #:(.*)Price");
Matcher mymatcher = mypattern.matcher("Manufacturer #: ABC company Price");
if (mymatcher.find()) {
    WhatIWant = mymatcher.group(1);
}
```

But I don't know how to combine them together, I tried `Manufacturer #:(.*)Price|Quantity` and seems like it is not working.

Any help would be appreciated!

Update: I just realized down the paragraph of text, there are some `price` and `quantity`, which where `*` search will eat up the whole text...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with *Lazy* `(.*?)` way along with *Ignore case*.

```
Pattern mypattern = 
         Pattern.compile("Manufacturer\\s*#?:\\s*(.*?)\\s*(Price|Quantity)",
                                                       Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher mymatcher = mypattern.matcher("Manufacturer #: ABC company Price");
if (mymatcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(mymatcher.group(1)); // ABC company
}
```

*Note:* match for multiple line

```
Pattern mypattern = 
         Pattern.compile("Manufacturer\\s*#?:\\s*(.*?)\\s*(Price|Quantity)",
                                   Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Get the matched group from index 1.

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/mA2hI5/5)

Comment: actually, the text contains `quantity` and `price` else where which `*` greedily eat up the whole paragraph..

Comment: As I used `.*?` so it will look in non-greedy way. Look at updated demo.